# How to initialise NSDate in a parameterised constructor in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

This is the code written in Objective C where I am initialising values into a parameterised constructor. While all the fields are taking entries properly, I am having trouble entering in the `NSDate` field. Given below is the Constructor declaration, implementation and finally the method call.

//Init declaration

```
-(instancetype)initWithParam1:(NSNumber*)customerId_ withParam2:   (NSString*)firstName_ withParam3:(NSString*)lastName_ withParam4:(NSDate*)dateOfBirth_ withParam5:(NSString*)address_ withParam6:(NSNumber*)mobileNumber_;
```

//Init definition

```
-(instancetype)initWithParam1:(NSNumber *)customerId_ withParam2:(NSString *)firstName_ withParam3:(NSString *)lastName_ withParam4:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth_ withParam5:(NSString *)address_ withParam6:(NSNumber *)mobileNumber_

{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.customerId = customerId_;
        self.firstName = firstName_;
        self.lastName = lastName_;
        self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth_;
        self.address = address_;
        self.mobileNumber = mobileNumber_;
    }
    return self;
```

//Init call

```
Customer *c1 = [[Customer alloc]initWithParam1:@1001 withParam2:@"Aman" withParam3:@"Zaidi" withParam4:@"22-05-1993" withParam5:@"Bangalore" withParam6:@9567812345];
```

Any suggestions on how to enter date in that field. Sorry for the naivety but I am totally new to Objective C and I am getting used to the syntaxes.

Comment: `@"22-05-1993"` is an `NSString`, not an `NSDate`.

Comment: And the value you pass to `param6` is an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. Phone numbers should be strings, not numbers. You don't do math on phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. :)

Comment: Except your "fixed" the phone number backwards. It should be a string, not a number.

Comment: The business logic demands the datatype be NSNumber and not NSString.

Comment: You're going to regret that decision. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *date* is a string.

You need to change the parameter to `NSString`

```
... withParam4:(NSString *)dateOfBirth_ ...
```

and in the init method convert the string to `NSDate` with `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
self.dateOfBirth = [formatter dateFromString:dateOfBirth_];
```

Comment: Careful converting a birthdate string to an `NSDate`. There will be timezone issues that will result in displaying that date with the wrong day.

Comment: Actually without specifying any locale or timezone the formatter is supposed to consider the current time zone.

Comment: Right. But when that date is later shown to some other user in another timezone, the conversion of the date to a string using that users's timezone can show the date as one day off from the original birthday string.